# Access vba How to test if a combobox's value is on a new rowsource list?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

Based on results from elsewhere in my form, sometimes the Row Source of a combobox is changed to a more restrictive query that includes many of the same items as the original.
Is there a way to test if the current value is on the new Row Source list?
If it is not on that list, I want to reset the combobox to blank, but if it is on the list, I want to leave it in place to prevent the need to re-enter it if it is still valid.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following to test if the current value of the combobox was in the results of the query.  Is this the best way to do this?

```
Forms(Form_Name).Controls("[Combobox_Name]").RowSource = "Query_Name"
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Query_Name")
rs.FindFirst ("[Table_Header]='" & [Forms]![Form_Name]![Combobox_Name]) & "'"
If rs.NoMatch Then
    Forms(Form_Name).Controls("[Combobox_Name]") = ""
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you plan to carry over a value from record to record this may work.  Assuming you are storing the value from the last record you could set the LimitToList property of the combobox to true and then call something like this:

```
On Error Goto SkipUpdate
Forms!Form_Name!Combobox_Name.RowSource = "Query_Name"
Forms!Form_Name!Combobox_Name.text = OldValue
...
```

It should throw an error preventing the field from being updated (defaulting to Null)